# MASS{lda} plot in R

Tags: r, self-study, data-visualization, discriminant-analysis

I'm reading the Introduction to statistical learning with R currently, but I blocked through a Lab about Discriminant analysis. So the thing is that we trying to fit a linear discriminant analysis model to Stock market data in order to predict the direction based on the last two days movement (Lag1&Lag2).
So far no problems, we fit the model through a training data set (train):

I used lda from MASS package.

```
ldam=lda(Direction~Lag1+Lag2,data=train)
response=predict(ldam,data=train)
```

Here, it gets weird for me. When we do the following line of code:

```
plot(ldam)
```

I get this:

[image]

Well, what I understood that this is a histogram for the linear discriminant function values for each of the 2 levels.
But with further investigations I found this:
[image]

First, the plot above indicates that we have negative values of the linear discriminant function for the 'Up' level. While, when I use the model to predict over the training data set, and subset it to only have the observations for we which we have Up as a prediction, I get that the minimum value doesn't reach the values in the plot above.
So what I hope to know is:
1- What are the x and y axis?
2- In case the x axis is the value of the LD function for an observation from the training data set, and the y axis is the number of its occurrence inside a given level (Up or Down). Why when I do it using predict function, I get contradicting results to the given plot. (Min of LD function for the 'Up' level is: -0.37 while on the plot it suggests arround -4 values.)

Thank you.

## EDIT:

After I saw this in another time I discovered what I was missing and the solution is as follows, the plots that plot(ldam) provides are actually based on the training data set. In a broad way the training data set is used to generate LD coefficients $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. Using these coefficients on the training data set in the form: $\alpha_1*Lag1+\alpha_2*Lag2$ and plot histograms based on which class they belong to (Up/Down).

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't provided anything--certainly not a counterexample.  There is no apparent relationship between the `response` object, the arguments to the `lda` command, or the plot.  The contorted code is also of concern: what is the reason you have not directly computed `response$x[response$class=='Up']`? This suggests the problem might be due to issues in undisclosed software commands you used to produce the example.

Comment: Okay, I apologize for not mentioning what response is. I edited the question. My question is -since I couldn't provide a counter example- is simply: What's the output of the plot(ldam) command. I don't want the interpretation of the result. I just want to know what's on the x axis and what's on the y axis. That's all. Thank you.

Comment: At the very least you need to tell us what package you are using!

Comment: Well it's the lda { MASS } for linear discriminant analysis.